# bold chapter with dottedtocline and tocbasic

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

I used `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry{dottedtocline}{chapter}` in order to get dots on chapters. Unfortunately the chapter entries aren't bold anymore. How to I get the it bold an keep the lines? The manual didn't help me on that one.

(I managed to do it with `tocstyle, but I don't want to use an alpha package...)

Thanks!

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry{dottedtocline}{chapter}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addchap{Einleitung}
\addchap{Hinweise}
\addsec{bla}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: AFAIK `dottedtocline` is only a compatibility style. AFAIR the KOMA-Script classes use style `tocline` or aliases and derived styles for each toc entry level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use option `toc=chapterentrywithdots`: (see sec 3.9 v3.15)

```
\documentclass[toc=chapterentrywithdots]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addchap{Einleitung}
\addchap{Hinweise}
\addsec{bla}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image: chapter entries with dots]

It does something like

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[toclinefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill]{chapter}
```

so it does not change the style of the entries but only changes the `linefill` feature of the TOC entry style.

Comment: Just noted: with `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[beforeskip=1pt]{tocline}{chapter}` the spacings will be the same everywhere. :)